# I have one issue in nodejs. I can´t add the middleware BodyParser

Tags: node.js

I have one error when I try to execute my file. I Received the following error.

[image]

The code of my file node.js

[image]

Comment: use npm install body-parser at command line

Comment: As of version 4 of express, it no longer includes the body parser, and must be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Is it correctly installed? Check your `package.json` or just install it again:

```
sudo npm install body-parser --save
```

Comment: `sudo` isn't necessary and generally should not be used in situations like this.